# Relationship wrong

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm really exhausted, i'm trying a make a relationship and can't do it, somebody can help me?

```
__tablename__ = 'Period'
id = db.Column(db.Integer)
hour = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
minute = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
sound_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Sound.id")), nullable=False)
sound = db.relationship("AudioModel", post_update=True)

_tablename_ = 'Sound'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
basename = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)
periods = db.relationship('PeriodModel', lazy='dynamic')
```

this gives me the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship AudioModel.periods - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Answer (score 0):

use `__tablename__` instead of `_tablename_` and that should fix it.